# I'm facing this issue in Arch Linux: Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, archlinux

I use arch linux, on a 64 bit system. I tried installing Android Studio, and the installation shows this error:

Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device
Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.

In the Android studio instruction website, for Ubuntu and Fedora, there were instructions for installing additional packages, but for Arch there is to be installed explicitly.

How do I resolve this?

I'm not sure what this error actually is. Would be really helpful if someone could please advice me how to resolve this.